# PHP fail to upload video but work with image

Tags: php, .htaccess, video

I don't know why i can't upload video to my server?

```
  $dirname = rand(10,99999);
  mkdir('hosting/' . $dirname);

  $to = 'hosting/' . $dirname . '/' .$_FILES['file']['name'];

  //Create .htaccess file
  $createHTACCESS = fopen('hosting/'.$dirname."/.htaccess", "w");
  fwrite($createHTACCESS,'
Options -Indexes
ini_set("upload_max_filesize", "30M");
ini_set("post_max_size", "30M");
ini_set("max_input_time", 400);
ini_set("max_execution_time", 400);
  ');
  fclose($createHTACCESS);

  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $to);
```

As you can how it work,when soem one upload some thing EP video,then it will create a dir for him and also a .htaccess file,and the .htaccess and other type of file like image it work just fine,but when change it to video it just can't upload,i try Googeing this,and the internet say if you want to upload some big thing you need to do this ,so i this .htaccess file to deal with it

[image]

But it still happening,so i check my free web hosting PHP config

[image]

Internet say it need 2MB but i have 10MB,so i rally don't know what happening

Comment: There is no point in writing the .htaccess file with php; the web-server has already processed all (if any...) .htaccess files when the php script is called. You should add a .htaccess file to the parent directory or set the values directly in the php.ini file.

Comment: I already did it,one is in my hosting folder one is at my root